# How to hide "Scripts Currently Forbidden" bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, noscript

Noscript pops up a "Scripts Currently Forbidden" bar at the bottom of any webpage I view.  How can I configure Noscript so that it never shows this bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I configure Noscript so that it never shows this bar?

1. Noscript > Options
2. Select "Notifications" tab
3. Disable (untick) "Show messages about blocked scripts"
4. Click "OK"

   [image]